# Google Speech to Text Error: Specify FLAC encoding to match file header

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

I am trying the Google Speech to Text sample for PHP.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/speech

I was able to transcribe the raw file correctly:

```
php speech.php transcribe test/data/audio32KHz.raw
```

But when I tried doing the same for a FLAC file (provided by Google in the sample)

`php speech.php transcribe test/data/audio32KHz.flac`

I got this error.

```
In ApiException.php line 139:

  {                                                              
      "message": "Specify FLAC encoding to match file header.",  
      "code": 3,                                                 
      "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",                              
      "details": []                                              
  }
```

I tried passing encoding too but that didn't work. I get the same error.

```
php speech.php transcribe --encoding FLAC test/data/audio32KHz.flac
```

Comment: Oof, I remember when I was working with the Google Speech SDK, there were a lot of issues around ensuring the service knew it was a FLAC file and that the reported sample rate matched the file and yeah, it a mission. I tried to look thru my code to see if I can find an answer for you, but I didn't find anything, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Use AWS Transcribe. It is easy to develop for and their documentation is much better.

Amazon cares about AWS. Google doesn't care about Google Cloud.